# Problem building python solution with c++ component in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I tried to open a project/solution twslink2pt.sln (a Python 3.6 wrapper with c++ component) using the Visual Studio 2017, the following message is displayed.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: twslink2pt, Configuration: Release Win32 
 ------
1>Performing Custom Build Tools
1>In order to function correctly, please ensure the following environment
   variables are correctly set:
1>PYTHON_INCLUDE:
1>PYTHON_LIB:
1>The system cannot find the path specified.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7   
  \IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006:    
  "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
1>Done building project "twslink2pt.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This project/solution twslink2pt.sln has different installation than mine. My python.exe is installed with Visual Studio 2017 and located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64. I am using Window 10.

I need to either adjust my python installation to match with what
is set in the project or adjust the project to match with my python installation.

How do I change the include path in the c++ settings in Visual Studio 2017 to point to the correct library (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include)?

For the linking I need the python36.lib. The python36.lib is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs. How do I include the python36.lib in the linking in Visual Studio 2017?

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[This section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#create-the-core-c-projects) of the official documentation describes how to configure a C++ project in detail, but the short answer is:

- Right-click the C++ project in Solution Explorer and select Properties
- Select "All Configurations" and "All Platforms" (or when entering different values for 64-bit and 32-bit, just select the platform you want) from the drop-down
- Expand C/C++, General and modify "Additional Include Directories" to have the `include` directory
- Expand Linker, General and modify "Additional Library Directories" to have the `libs` directory

For the project you are using, it may be looking at environment variables. Another way to set these is to open "Developer Command Prompt for {Visual Studio Version}" from Start, type `set PYTHON_INCLUDE=<path>`, `set PYTHON_LIB=<path>` and then `devenv` to start Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Zooba, Thanks a lot. After setting environment variables, this message is displayed 1>PYTHON_INCLUDE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include
1>PYTHON_LIB: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs
1>The system cannot find the path specified.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
1>Done building project "twslink2pt.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: Hi Zooba, Thank you very much. Don't know why Visual Studio cannot find the path specified. The two files are there and the file names are correct. This is the output from command prompt:                                                                           C:\>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs>